# How can I add RRA's to an existing RRD?

Tags: python, rrdtool, rrd

I am using RRD for monitoring. In the current RRD files are not all archives present that I want to use in the future. How do I add RRA's to an existing RRD? I'm writing a Python (1.4.7) script using rrdpython.

I only find the option for dumping it to XML, adding the archives and restoring it again. But that doesn't sound attractive and fast.

If there is no good solution, how can I easily 'copy' the content of the RRD to add it to a new RRD (by using 'update' I guess) which does contain the archives? (in python)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under RRDTool 1.4 and earlier, you cannot add a DS or an RRA to an existing RRD file without recreating it.  The newly-released RRDTool 1.5 has the ability to add new DS and RRA using the `rrdtool tune` subcommand, but this may not yet have Python bindings available in your OS.

With 1.4, the only way to add a new RRA is to dump the existing file to XML, modify the XML, and then restore it to create a new RRD.  Needless to say, this is not trivial, and does not necessarily build the data in the new RRA from historical data in other RRAs.  There exist various third-party utilities such as `rrdmerge` (distributed with the Routers2 package) that can do this, but they all have shortcomings in one form or another.